# Solve equation for one variable

Tags: equation-solving, functions, resolve

I have the following two equations,

```
di - (39.18 (0.07 + 2.61 (de + di)^0.28) + 
    1891.93 (de - di)^0.218)/(0.0119 + 0.0626 (de + di)^0.28)=0
```

and

```
de - (724.85 (0.17 + 2.61 (de - di)^0.28) + 
102.26 (de - di)^0.28)/(0.0119 + 0.0626 (de + di)^0.28)=0
```

I want to solve these equations for de and di, however, solve is taking too much time. Is there any alternative in mathematica.

Comment: FindInstance[{di - (39.18  (0.07 + 2.61  (de + di)^0.28) + 
       1891.93  (de - di)^0.218)/(0.0119 + 0.0626  (de + di)^0.28) == 
   0, de - (724.85  (0.17 + 2.61  (de - di)^0.28) + 
       102.26  (de - di)^0.28)/(0.0119 + 0.0626  (de + di)^0.28) == 
   0}, {de, di}]

Comment: FindRoot[{di - (39.18  (0.07 + 2.61  (de + di)^0.28) + 
        1891.93  (de - di)^0.218)/(0.0119 + 0.0626  (de + di)^0.28) ==
     0, de - (724.85  (0.17 + 2.61  (de - di)^0.28) + 
        102.26  (de - di)^0.28)/(0.0119 + 0.0626  (de + di)^0.28) == 
    0}, {de, 10000}, {di, 10000}] // Chop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) and [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) the equations

```
eqns = {di - (39.18  (0.07 + 2.61  (de + di)^0.28) + 
         1891.93  (de - di)^0.218)/(0.0119 + 0.0626  (de + di)^0.28) == 0,
    de - (724.85  (0.17 + 2.61  (de - di)^0.28) + 
         102.26  (de - di)^0.28)/(0.0119 + 0.0626  (de + di)^0.28) == 0} // 
   Rationalize // Simplify

(* {di == (2 (13713 + 9459650 (de - di)^(109/500) + 511299 (de + di)^(7/25)))/(
  119 + 626 (de + di)^(7/25)), 
 de == (5 (246449 + 3988237 (de - di)^(7/25)))/(119 + 626 (de + di)^(7/25))} *)

(sol = NSolve[eqns, {de, di}, Reals]) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {19.8772, {{de -> 21177.3, di -> 13061.1}, {de -> 6354.62, di -> 6315.78}}} *)
```

Check the solutions:

```
eqns /. sol

(* {{False, False}, {False, False}} *)
```

There is a precision issue. Use [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) to refine the solutions:

```
sol2 = FindRoot[eqns, {{de, #[[1]]}, {di, #[[2]]}}] & /@ ({de, di} /. sol)

{{de -> 21177.3, di -> 13061.1}, {de -> 6354.62, di -> 6315.78}}
```

Checking the refined solutions:

```
eqns /. sol2

(* {{True, True}, {True, True}} *)
```

The differences are small.

```
({de, di} /. sol) - ({de, di} /. sol2)

(* {{-1.19799*10^-8, -5.61886*10^-9}, {-2.89638*10^-8, -4.33574*10^-8}} *)
```